# Override NSManagedObject getter for localized string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

I have a bunch of NSManagedObject entities in which I have a set of fields which needs to be translated properly.

I've read other posts about best practices for core data localization, however I was really hoping there was a method to centralize the management of the resolution of properly translated strings from keys related to entities.

So for example if I have an entity called Books with a field localizedDescription, instead of creating a relationship with a LocalizedBook which is an entity created just for the purpose of translation, I'd love to have all entities related to real world abstractions, and a unique entity, which could be also a strings file or a NSDictionary.

This way I'd love to create a subclass of NSManagedObject and a super class of Book in wich the getters for the fields, conditionally, could read the raw value or do some math and then return the translated value.

So what I am asking here is basically: how can I -with subclassing or categories- override the getter of every NSManagedObject field without writing the getter for every field or looping the fields? Is there a method I could override, like valueForKey:, without breaking anything?

For the sake of curiosity, I am more interested in this specific problem than to find the better way to solve the translation problem or the absolute best practice for translating core data values.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant override getters without writing them. Both `-valueForKey:` and `-primitiveValueForKey:` should not be overridden.

UPD: May be overriding such methods, as NSObject's `-methodForSelector:` will do a trick.

Comment: I checked Apple docs, and only primitiveValueForKey is listed in the should-not-override list. 

Anyways I'm sorry but I didn't understand how to user -methodForSelector:

Comment: Write your own implementation (IMP) for what you want to do when getter called, then combine it with default implementation of the getter and return combination of those functions.

Comment: `valueForKey:`'s description also states that it shouldn't be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

How about just keeping all the values in one language in your store and then use `NSLocalizedString` to translate them when you need to display them in your app?

Comment: if you mean having a database and a .strings file that doesn't sound right to me, as you'll be forced to keep them in sync. Besides, if your translated data comes from a server it's easier and more efficient to save them in a core data database in my opinion.

Comment: anyway my question was about overriding NSManagedObject getters, so I feel the focus should be there instead of on the translation issue.